# What does a capacitor marked "105 | 47 μF" mean?

Tags: capacitor, schematic

Attached schematic for the e-Paper driver HAT.

The meaning of the yellow marked part is not clear to me.

[image]

Does this mean I can replace 105 (1 μF) with 4.7 μF and use either as available?

[The entire schematic can be found here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hE1a7wRdHbJu7Z7ePIGmB6oZyJvBYokl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You might want to ask from who made the schematics. Or just look at what the e-paper display requires. It can't be deciphered what is meant here with that notation.

Comment: @Justme Its from waveshare, I didn't find any forum there to ask it. But I'll try again.

Comment: It's 105 and it means 1uF. 150 would mean 15pF, unreasonably low value.

Comment: @Justme 105/50V seems different than 105|4.7uF. As in 105/50V is it sure, we required only 105 capacitors with 50V capacity. But I have doubt is what would affect if I change 4.7uf where 105 is required (105|4.7uF). Is it possible these small value capacitors can affect the working of PCB for a long time?

Comment: Yes I know what you mean and it can't be answered because we don't know why the caps are marked weirdly and we don't know if the e-paper display module you will use requires 1uF or 4.7uF capacitors to work or even if it makes any difference. But it is possible that it makes a difference.

Comment: Could it mean a 105 (1uF) in parallel with a 4.7uF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean I can replace 105 (1 μF) with 4.7 μF and use either as available?

In this *specific* case yes, though this isn't a standard marking as others have mentioned. It seems to be an artifact of the history of these documents, as I found out. It is NOT a "caps-in-parallel" mark, as JRE's answer suggests.

I've actually been working on miniaturizing this very board recently. Waveshare's documentation is rather confusing, so to figure out what I needed, I consulted:

- the actual breakout "hat" schematic, including [the history of that document](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:E-Paper-Driver-HAT-Schematic.pdf) on their wiki
- various versions of eink manuals from their site, including the history of those documents on their wiki
- Adafruit breakout schematic & Open source design
- CrystalFontz breakout schmatics

Comparing those, I found that Waveshare has recently bumped up the size of the caps to 4.7µF, but have historically been smaller at 1µF. I'm unimpressed with their document skills.

Here is a snippet of the relevant part of the table that I extracted from these resources when I was trying to decipher this myself, showing marked values and voltage rating:

| name | eink v3 | eink v2 | newer hat | older hat | Adafruit | CrystalFontz | CF-rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VSH | 4.7/25 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 1u/25 | 1u/25 | 10V~17V |
| PreVGH | 4.7/25 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 1u/25 | 1u/50 | ~22V |
| VSL | 4.7/25 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 1u/25 | 1u/25 | -17V~ -10V |
| PreVGL | 4.7/25 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 105/50 | 1u/25 | 1u/50 | ~ -20V |

As you can see, it looks like the newest hat is a mix of eink v3 and the "newer hat" version.

As for me, I ended up using 105/50 (1.0µF 50V rating) as that fit the rest of the project (and I had on hand) and it is working fine for me today.

Answer (score 0):

> What does a capacitor marked "105 | 47 μF" mean?

**"105 | 47 μF"** - a 47 μF electrolytic capacitor with a maximum operating temperature of 105° C.

**"105 / 50 V"** - a 1 μF 50 V ceramic capacitor.